# Domain name setup without A Records

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cname

I am hosting content on AWS and want to configure my DNS settings so that both my @ record and www record point at my Elastic Load Balancer.

- example.com (@ record)
- www.example.com (www record)

AWS recommends setting up domains using CNAMEs as the IP addresses can change.

All the documentation I have seen on the CNAME is that they deal with subdomains but not the primary domain itself (http://example.com
). The primary domain requires an A record and therefore must require an IP address.

I do not want to use an A Record to point the traffic to my Elastic Load Balancer as the IP address may change.

Any idea how I can get around this issue?

I am using Linode to manage my DNS.

Comment: Just a note: the solution proposed by @Volkan Paksoy only works if you move the domain to AWS's Route53 DNS service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a special record type in Route 53 called "Alias".

> Q. Can I point my zone apex (example.com versus www.example.com) at my
>   Elastic Load Balancer?
>
> Yes. Amazon Route 53 offers a special type of record called an ‘Alias’
>   record that lets you map your zone apex (example.com) DNS name to your
>   ELB DNS name (i.e. elb1234.elb.amazonaws.com). IP addresses associated
>   with Amazon Elastic Load Balancers can change at any time due to
>   scaling up, scaling down, or software updates. Route 53 responds to
>   each request for an Alias record with one or more IP addresses for the
>   load balancer. Queries to Alias records that are mapped to ELB load
>   balancers are free. These queries are listed as
>   “Intra-AWS-DNS-Queries” on the Amazon Route 53 usage report.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/

Just set the Alias to Yes and you will be able to choose your load balancer from the dropdown menu:

[image]